# Can't find the maven repository for xwiki xmlrpc

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, xwiki

I want to include this library:

```
import org.xwiki.xmlrpc.XWikiXmlRpcClient;
```

so I am using this maven snippet to include it:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.xwiki.platform</groupId>
<artifactId>xwiki-core-xmlrpc-client </artifactId>
<version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I can't find the library anywhere though. We use Artifactory which queries the main maven repo for unresolved dependencies. I can find the jar online, but I need a maven repository to include it in the build process.

Do I need to add a special repo or something?

Comment: Add http://maven.xwiki.org/releases/ as repository in you pom.xml or settings.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list can be found at at their [website](http://dev.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Community/Building) :

```
  <repositories>
   <repository>
     <id>xwiki-snapshots</id>
     <name>XWiki Nexus Snapshot Repository Proxy</name>
     <url>http://nexus.xwiki.org/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
     <releases>
       <enabled>false</enabled>
     </releases>
     <snapshots>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
     </snapshots>
   </repository>
   <repository>
     <id>xwiki-releases</id>
     <name>XWiki Nexus Releases Repository Proxy</name>
     <url>http://nexus.xwiki.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
     <releases>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
     </releases>
     <snapshots>
       <enabled>false</enabled>
     </snapshots>
   </repository>
 </repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
   <pluginRepository>
     <id>xwiki-plugins-snapshots</id>
     <name>XWiki Nexus Plugin Snapshot Repository Proxy</name>
     <url>http://nexus.xwiki.org/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots</url>
     <releases>
       <enabled>false</enabled>
     </releases>
     <snapshots>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
     </snapshots>
   </pluginRepository>
   <pluginRepository>
     <id>xwiki-plugins-releases</id>
     <name>XWiki Nexus Plugin Releases Repository Proxy</name>
     <url>http://nexus.xwiki.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
     <releases>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
     </releases>
     <snapshots>
       <enabled>false</enabled>
     </snapshots>
   </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Thank you - I found every page on the Xwiki site except that one :)